# How to replace an url string paramter with an php array

Tags: php, urlencode

Currently I have this url with paramanters. The $filter is in string format and rawurlencoded. Is it possible to use an array instead of string for the $filter? Like `array('groups'=>array('11','22','33'))`?
Here's a sample code that is working.

```
$endpoint = 'https://api.com/queries';
$filter = "groups:['11', '22', '33']";
$url = $endpoint . '?filter=' . rawurlencode($filter);
```

It produces this url:

```
https://api.com/queries?filter=groups%3A%5B%2711%27%2C%20%2722%27%2C%20%2733%27%5D
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `urlencode()` function just after to use `json_encode()` function like this :

```
$endpoint = 'https://api.com/queries';

$filterArray = array('groups' => array('11', '22', '33'));

$filter = urlencode(json_encode($filterArray));

$url = $endpoint . '?filter=' . $filter;
```

After this you can decode the URL-encoded JSON string and convert it back to an array like this :.

```
$filterString = $_GET['filter'];
$filterArray = json_decode(urldecode($filterString), true);
```

Comment: Here's the created url `https://api.com/queries?filter=%7B%22groups%22%3A%5B%2211%22%2C%2222%22%2C%2233%22%5D%7D` but still not working. I've tried decoding it using burp suite and it has curly bracket on it. `https://api.com/queries?filter={"groups":["11","22","33"]}`